# What shortcuts to comment (line, block) in dbt Cloud IDE?

Tags: ide, cloud, dbt

I've been searching for a while without finding the way to quickly comment with a shortcut in the dbtCloud IDE. This would be really useful and save me a lot of time.

As far as you know, is there any shortcut to comment a line ? Several lines ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Control K C will comment a line or block of lines.

Control K U will uncomment a line or block of lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! 
It seems it doesn't work for Mac OS users, do you have the shortcuts for Mac keyboards please ?

Comment: How about Command K C?  Sorry I'm not familiar with Macs.  Also, I mean hold Command and then push K and then C, as opposed to pushing K and C simultaneously.

Comment: Assuming DBT uses the same shortcuts that Visual Studio Code does, try ⌘/ (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/keyboard-shortcuts?view=vsmac-2022)

Comment: You were right with CMD+K, then C. Thank you for this precision I didn't get it before. So it's similar between platforms that's pretty cool ! Thx